# Docker Python ENV returns sh: flake8: not found

Tags: python, docker, python-venv

I am submitting my file patterns and files. Please go through if needed.

My question is when I try this -> [`docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"`], it returns "`sh: flake8: not found`"

**requirements.txt**

```
Django>=4.2.5
djangorestframework>=3.14.0
```

**requirements.dev.txt**

```
flake8>=6.1.0
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:alpine3.18
LABEL maintainer="Gazi"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [$DEV = "true"]; \
    then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
    --disabled-password \ 
    --no-create-home \
    django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

**.flake8** inside app location

```
[flake8]
exclude =
    migrations,
    __pycache__,
    manage.py,
    settings.py
```

When I try this -> [`docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"`], it returns "`sh: flake8: not found`"

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error in your shell script. Consider the following example:

```
$ DEV=false
$ if [$DEV = true]; then
> echo hello world
> fi
bash: [false: command not found
```

`[` is just the name of a command; as with any other command you need a space between the command name and arguments, and spaces between arguments:

```
if [ $DEV = true ]; then ...
```

If you rewrite your `Dockerfile` like this...

```
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; \
    then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
    --disabled-password \ 
    --no-create-home \
    django-user
```

...it will probably work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! 
Nothing returned from the terminal, my guess is it worked.